# Show div section in full size in any screen size

Tags: jquery, css

I want to display div section Full screen when website is loaded. When someone is scroll down again new div section comes with full screen that fit to any led resolution.
Here are the demo website.
http://thestory.barbour.com/timeline/2014/barbour-today.

Please help me or give me some reference jquery links or css.

Comment: i think you want to use `.scroll()` event and slide the next/prev divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the wonderful plugin fullPage.js

[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage)